# How to create a custom ViewGroup which contains buttons and graphics lines for a 2D game board in android?

Tags: android, button, onclick, draw, viewgroup

[image]

The above picture is a part of my game-board I am developing. I need to create a board like this where I can put new pieces at nodes or move the existing piece on board(red one) to adjacent places.

To accomplish this I thought to create a custom ViewGroup which will contain my pieces as buttons. While implementing this, following questions came to my mind

1. The buttons(in red) which will be inside my ViewGroup, will be mentioned inside XML layout file or inside my custom ViewGroup class? If I want to mention in my XML file how to access those in my custom ViewGroup class?
2. How can I draw these black game-board lines in my custom ViewGroup class?
3. How to take action on clicking the red buttons on the game-board?
4. Should I use SurfaceView for this? Its a simple 2D game without any animations.

I will be very grateful, if someone can answer these above questions.

Comment: ad 1) you can add your buttons both in xml or your custom `ViewGroup` code ad 2) override `draw` / `dispatchDraw` method

Answer (score 0):

you can use canvass to draw lines and circle in onDraw(Canvas canvas) method where you extents the view class.